# How to change the button icons on the MATLAB figure toolbar? (2014b)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I'm writing an application in MATLAB and want to update the look of it. is it possible to change the icons of the buttons in the toolbar in MATLAB code?

The code will be compiled and I am not using GUIDE; ideally there's a way to get the button handles and set each icon individually although I don't know how I would do this.

[image: Example of what I mean]

But with higher quality icons.

Comment: This may be against the Terms and Conditions that you agreed to while buying and installing MATLAB

Comment: The icon images are fixed at 16x16 resolution -> so you cant improve the resolution to provide "higher quality" images

Comment: @Wolfie - I agree - but I thought it was worth highlighting to readers that the resolution size is fixed.

Comment: @SardarUsama id this against the T&Cs then that would be super useful to know also. One step at a time!

Comment: @J.Derrick A quick message to MathWorks might be the easiest way to get that info. Editing these buttons isn't explicitly documented, but the objects are pretty exposed so I'd be surprised if there was an issue - if they're that concerned they could have made the figure objects hidden!

Comment: I couldn't find that info on the web but I suggest to make it sure. Btw changing the appearance of title bar is against the t&c https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91579-

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of this. It primarily concerns the MATLAB logo and 'titlebar' and given that the MATLAB logo is in a different bar and the MATLAB code in Wolfie's answer refers to the 'FigureToolBar' I think it is safe to say they are not the same thing.

Comment: I didn't say or doubt them to be the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you can change the figure toolbar icons, or add your own.**

I've detailed how to change the icon below, as well as other useful things to do with the toolbar whilst you're editing the properties anyway.

See the code comments for details.

**Get the toolbar object**

```
% Initialise some figure 
fig = figure( 'Name', 'MyApp', 'NumberTitle', 'off' )
% Get the figure toolbar handle
tbar = findall( fig, 'tag', 'FigureToolBar' );
```

You can do `findall(tbar)` at this point to list the names of all the buttons

**Hiding buttons**

Let's say you want to hide the "new figure" button:

```
% Get the button from the tbar object
btn = findall( tbar, 'tag', 'Standard.NewFigure' )
% Set to not visible
set( btn, 'Visible', 'off' );
```

**Changing callbacks**

Let's say you want the print button to trigger a print-preview callback instead of printing directly (you could assign any custom callback function to any button):

```
% Get the button again
btn = findall( tbar, 'tag', 'Standard.PrintFigure' );
% Change the callback (and the tooltip to match)
set( btn, 'ClickedCallback', 'printpreview(gcbf)', ...
          'TooltipString', 'Print preview' );
```

**Changing the icon**

At this point you can see all button attributes are editable, including the image as per your original question.

In particular, just change the `CData` property:

```
% Update the print button to have a print preview icon
% This should be a 16*16 RBG image matrix, use imread to get from file
img = imread( 'printpreview.bmp' )
% Assign CData property to button already acquired
set( btn, 'CData', img );
```

Output (I used a random print preview icon, seen 4th from the left):

[image: figure]

**Add new buttons**

You can add new buttons by simply creating `uipushtool` objects (with CData property set for the icon image) with the `tbar` object as a parent.

**Change the separators**

The vertical grey separators can be added or removed (useful for creating your own button groups or when removing buttons). Simply set the `'Separator'` property to `'off'` or `'on'`, for a separator on the left side of a button.

---

For a compiled app, this may be against The MathWorks T&Cs, but this is the *how to* not the *should you* do this!

Comment: Looking into T&Cs is the next step, thank you for the help!

Comment: You can also add `uitoggletool` as well as `uipushtool` buttons.